# Visual Studio 2019 forgets expanded/collapsed code blocks in C# projects after reloading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

At work, my VS2019 no longer retains the state of collapsed/expanded code blocks when file is reopened. This is not an issue back at home. I more or less use the same extensions. I deleted the .vs folders, reset the VS settings, and still does not remember it. What options or extension do I need to change/install/remove for this to work?

I've tried to search for this, but never about this exact issue.

Comment: Could it be `Tools | Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> [x] Enter outlining mode when files open` ?

Comment: I may have seek that option, but it is already on.

Comment: I've upgraded VS after which it was crashing with `NullReferenceException`. I ended up completely uninstall then reinstall it which also fixed this issue. I even reinstalled the extensions I had and still works. Don't know what have happened.